# How to retrieve IAM temporary credentials in kubernetes.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-iam

This application runs perfectly when I pass my temporary AWS credentials as shown. Obviously, this isn't best practice. How can I programatically get the credentials from the IAM role? Can I somehow run aws sts assume-role from the kubernetes.yaml? Assume I don't have access to the code base to use the DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: test
  annotations:
    iam.amazonaws.com/permitted: ".*"

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: application
  labels:
    app: application
  namespace: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        iam.amazonaws.com/role: Role
        awsRegion: us-east-1
      labels:
        app: application
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/xxxx:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          name: application
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: NUM_OF_DAYS
              value: "1"
            - name: NUM_OF_THREADS
              value: "24"
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              value: xxxxx
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              value: xxxxx
            - name: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
              value: xxxxxx
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 1Gi
            limits:
              memory: 1Gi
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is not a feature of Kubernetes. And would be broken if it was, since env vars can only be set at startup and role credentials rotate over time. You can write a wrapper for your program that sets things in env vars but it will have to restart the subprocess on rotation.